# Using $.ajax to send data via HttpPost in aspnet5, is not working

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

Ok basically I have a column, and when you click the header a couple of input tags appear dynamically, to change column name and submit it. I want to change it and show it right away using ajax. The code to do this is below, and sorry but the code is in coffee script. Also I am using ASPNET5 RC1 with MVC6.

```
SumbitColumnForm = () ->
$('.panel-heading').on 'click', 'input.ColumnTitleSumbit', (event) ->
    event.preventDefault();

    columnName = $('.NewColumnName').val().trim()
    columnNumber = $(this).parent().parent().attr 'id'

    newColumnData = "{ 
        'ColumnName': 'columnName'
        'ColumnNumber': 'columnNumber'
    }"      

    $.ajax
        url: '/Board/ChangeColumnName',
        type: 'POST'
        dataType: 'json',
        data: newColumnData,
        success: (data) -> 
                #res = $.parseJSON(data);
                alert "Hit the Success part";

        error: (xhr, err) ->
            alert("readyState: " + xhr.readyState + "\nstatus: " + xhr.status);
            alert("responseText: " + xhr.responseText);
```

The controller actions are

```
  [Route("{p_BoardName}")]
    public IActionResult Show(string p_BoardName)
    {
        m_Board.BoardName = p_BoardName;
        ViewData["BoardName"] = m_Board.BoardName;
        return View(m_Board);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult ChangeColumnName(ColumnModel newColumnData)
    {
        string name = newColumnData.ColumnName;
        m_Board.ColumnList[newColumnData.ColumnNumber].ColumnName = name;
        return View("Show", m_Board);
    }
```

Also the modelS if needed

```
public class ColumnModel
{
    private string m_name;
    private int m_columnNumber;

    public int ColumnNumber { get { return m_columnNumber; } }
    public string ColumnName { get { return m_name;} set { m_name = value; } }

    public ColumnModel(string p_Name, int p_ColumnNumber)
    {
        m_name = p_Name;
        m_columnNumber = p_ColumnNumber;
    }
}


public class BoardModel
{
    private string m_BoardName;
    private List<ColumnModel> m_ColumnList;


    [Required]
    public string BoardName { get { return m_BoardName; } set { m_BoardName = value; } }

    public List<ColumnModel> ColumnList
    {
        get { return m_ColumnList; }
        set { m_ColumnList = value; }
    }

}
```

So I have debugged both the Javascript and the controller action ChangeColumnName, and it is not hitting it. The javascript also does not hit the success part  of the ajax call also. I have tried everything that comes to mind and done a lot of googling but it just won't work. I feel like it is because of the way I am sending the data for the $.ajax call but really I just don't know why this doesn't work.

Also if i want to update the column name, by removing the input and adding the normal HTML to display the name, am I right to return a view in the action method ChangeColumnName? I mean will it reload the page or add it dynamically. Will I have to add JS code in the success attribute of the  $.ajax call to change it dynamically?

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Edit: Added the board model

Edit2: Updating showing the html code as a request of Stephen.

Using bootstrap column/grid design, and also bootstrap panels. I basically have  column shown by html

```
<div id="1" class="panel panel-default BoardColumn">
   <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">Something1</h3>
   </div>
 </div>
```

I want to change the header class 'panel-title' and update it dynamically without reloading the page. I have set up another ajax call, so when the header is clicked a few input tags are added and and the html is changed to the following. In minimal explaining I have done this using jquery append and remove functions.

```
   <div id="1" class="panel panel-default BoardColumn">
       <div class="panel-heading">
         <input class="PreviousColumnName" type="hidden" style="display: none;" value="Something1">
        <input class="NewColumnName" name="ColumnName">
       <input class="ColumnTitleSumbit" type="submit" value="Continue">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Now I want to get the value of the input with class name 'NewcolumnName', update the current column name in the model and place its new name. When the submit button is clicked, I want to remove the input tags and go back to the original html before that, showings it new column name without reloading.

Comment: What routing do you have set up? You have attribute on the other action but not the Ajax POST one.

Comment: You model does not have a parameterless constructor (so it cannot be initialized). And the properties don't even have setter, so could never be set.

Comment: @DavidG I dont have a route on that attribute because I am returning the view 'show' to update the page dynamically with the new columnname from the model.

Comment: One problem is I have put a breakpoint on that action method using Visual studio and it is not hitting it.

Comment: @Foysal94, It will never hit it because your model cannot be initialized - an exception is thrown before the code in the method if run (refer my previous comment)

Comment: How come visual studio doesn't show this exception or something to hint at me.. Should I be returning a view to show to update the column with its new name? I am not sure how to update it when I have the new column data. Why do I need a setter on the columnumber property and am I updating the model correctly?

Comment: Because your making an ajax call from the browser. Use your browser tools (Network tab) to inspect the response and you will see the details of the error. You also not specifying `contentType: 'json'` so that will also throw an exception

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104217/discussion-between-foysal94-and-stephen-muecke).

Comment: Ah yes, I see now. Thank you very much. Figured out my object was not getting sent properly aswell, as jquery/aspnet was sending a wrongly formatted json object. Now I am using JSON.stringify and it is sending the right data, and set my contenttype to 'application/json'. Whats the easiest way to update the column name straight away? How should I go about it.