# $.ajax to send data vis HttpPost in aspnet5 is not working

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

this is a followup question to the one here [Using $.ajax to send data via HttpPost in aspnet5, is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35564754/using-ajax-to-send-data-via-httppost-in-aspnet5-is-not-working?noredirect=1#comment58818713_35564754)

I have made the changes requested in the comments and a few other changes such as using the Json package from Newtonsoft.

Basically I have a column, and when you click the header a couple of input tags appear dynamically, to change column name and submit it. I want to change it and show it right away using ajax. The code to do this is below, and sorry but the code is in coffee script. Also I am using ASPNET5 RC1 with MVC6.

```
SumbitColumnForm = () ->
$('.panel-heading').on 'click', 'input.ColumnTitleSumbit', (event) ->
    event.preventDefault();

    columnName = $('.NewColumnName').val().trim()
    columnNumber = $(this).parent().parent().attr 'id'

    $.ajax
        url: '/Board/ChangeColumnName',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        data: JSON.stringify({ColumnName: columnName, ColumnNumber: columnNumber}) 
        success: (data) ->              
                 alert "Hit the Success part"
                 alert 'data is' + data
                 panelHeading = $('input.ColumnTitleSubmit').parent()
                 $(panelHeading).html("<h3 class='panel-title'> <h3>").text(data)

        error: (xhr, err) ->
            alert("readyState: " + xhr.readyState + "\nstatus: " + xhr.status);
            alert("responseText: " + xhr.responseText);
```

The relevant action methods from the controller are below

```
[Route("{p_BoardName}")]
    public IActionResult Show(string p_BoardName)
    {
        m_Board.BoardName = p_BoardName;
        ViewData["BoardName"] = m_Board.BoardName;
        return View(m_Board);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult ChangeColumnName(string newColumnData)
    {
        ColumnModel column = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ColumnModel>(newColumnData);
        // Update column name in the board model, the board model stores a list of columns
        m_Board.ColumnList[column.ColumnNumber].ColumnName = column.ColumnName; 

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject( m_Board.ColumnList[column.ColumnNumber]);

        return Json(json);
    }
```

Also the column and board models are below

```
public class ColumnModel
{
    private string m_name;
    private int m_columnNumber;

    public int ColumnNumber { get { return m_columnNumber; } set {m_columnNumber = value;} }
    public string ColumnName { get { return m_name;} set { m_name = value; } }

    public ColumnModel(string p_Name, int p_ColumnNumber)
    {
        m_name = p_Name;
        m_columnNumber = p_ColumnNumber;
    }

    public ColumnModel() { }
}




 public class BoardModel
{
    private string m_BoardName;
    private List<ColumnModel> m_ColumnList;


    [Required]
    public string BoardName { get { return m_BoardName; } set { m_BoardName = value; } }

    public List<ColumnModel> ColumnList
    {
        get { return m_ColumnList; }
        set { m_ColumnList = value; }
    }

}
```

I have done a lot of googling and I still can't get this to work. The request is not hitting the success attribute and is hitting the error attribute. I still get a 200 status code to show it is OK, and for some reason my data is a long html file, or in this case the 'Show' view from the board controller. I have requested requested Json and I am getting html. I don't know what is going on, I feel what might be going wrong is the http post method ChangeColumnName in the controller. Maybe I am not receiving or sending a valid JSON object.  Any help will be greatly appreicated.

Comment: Your POST method is `public JsonResult ChangeColumnName(string newColumnData)` but it should be `public JsonResult ChangeColumnName(ColumnModel model)` and the model will be correctly bound with both values. The return value needs to be `return Json(model.ColumnName);` - but why on earth are you returning a value you just sent from the client? -  you can just use `$(panelHeading).html("<h3 class='panel-title'> <h3>").text(columnName)` You also need to remove `contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',` and use `data: {ColumnName: columnName, ColumnNumber: columnNumber })`

Comment: I have done all the changes and now it is hitting the success part of the ajax call. The thing that am still confused about is, when I alert 'data is' + data in the success call, it alerts a whole html page, and to be exact the show.cshtml page. I don't understand why, when in the controller action method I told it to return just model.columnName which I presume the method is returning just a string/text and no json

Comment: It could not possibly alert the `show.cshtml` html unless your ajax call was hitting the `Show()` method so I can only assume you have some other errors/typos in your code. And `return Json(model.ColumnName);` does return `json`, (not `text`) - it just contains that text

Answer (score 0):

You are supplying the correct variable
in ajax

```
data: {ColumnName: columnName, ColumnNumber: columnNumber}
```

In controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult ChangeColumnName(string ColumnName, int ColumnNumber)
    {
       ..your code..
    }
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The key here is [ValidateInput(false)]

Try this :

Rather than sending a JSON.stringify, just send it as an object which means

```
var Data = {ColumnName: columnName, ColumnNumber: columnNumber};
```

You were already doing this from your link!

Change your signature to receive your ColumnModel directly rather than a string and add the attribute [ValidateInput(false)] to your action.  You'll not need to deserialize with this approach!

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
public JsonResult ChangeColumnName(ColumnModel newColumnData)
{
   Console.WriteLine(newColumnData.ColumnName);
}
```

Let me know if this solves your problem!

Comment: I had the exact same problem, the controller wasn't being hit and it was because the string sent to the controller had special characters that the controller tries to parse but doesn't succeed so someone told me to add the attribute [ValidateInput(false)] and it worked like a charm.  Of course this is because the value sent is known to be safe otherwise you need to encode and decode special characters exchanged between controller and client via ajax

Comment: When I look at the post request of my firefox debugger and in the network panel, I can see what is sent under the params tab. It sent the following :{"ColumnName":"ewfsdfbh","ColumnNumber":"1"}. So the controller cannot parse a few of these characters?  I will need to validate the string later at some point, for sql queries that can drop the table or just mess up the application in general. So I am not sure if [ValidateInput(false)] is the best approach in the long time.

Comment: Also am using JSON.stringify because the way jquery sends JSON data. For some reason it will covernt the data to something along the lines of ColumnName=columnName&ColumnNumber=columnNumber.

Comment: Also am using ASPNET5, dnxcore451 and dnx50 and I when add the attribute [ValidateInput(false)], the framework cannot find it. Asks me if I am missing a assembly reference.

Comment: If you're not using MVC which the attribute is part of System.Web.Mvc then make sure your strings transmitted to the controller are really clean of any special character and invisible one.